# 5 star rating with SVG and SCSS: hover does not work

Tags: html, css, sass

I have been trying to make an SVG 5 star rating with just SCSS and I followed [this](https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh) source. The original link uses font-awesome and I am trying to use SVG instead. However, I am failing to get the hover working (i.e. change color of stars upon hoving).

SCSS

```
$icons: (
        "half-star":
        '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 19"><path d="M20 7.2c-0.1-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.8-0.7l-5.7-0.8 -2.5-5.1C10.7 0.2 10.4 0 10 0c0 0 0 0 0 0l0 0C9.6 0 9.2 0.2 9 0.6L6.5 5.7l-5 0.7L0.9 6.5c0 0 0 0 0 0l0 0c0 0-0.1 0-0.1 0 -0.1 0-0.1 0-0.2 0.1 -0.1 0-0.2 0.1-0.2 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.1 0-0.1 0.1-0.2 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1-0.1 0.1 0 0-0.1 0.1-0.1 0.1 0 0.1 0 0.2 0 0.3C0 7.7 0.1 8 0.3 8.2l4.1 4 -1 5.6c-0.1 0.4 0.1 0.8 0.4 1C4.1 19 4.4 19 4.6 19c0.1 0 0.2 0 0.3-0.1l5.1-2.7 0.1 0v0l5.1 2.7c0.3 0.2 0.8 0.2 1.1-0.1 0.3-0.2 0.5-0.6 0.4-1l-1-5.6 4.1-4C20 7.9 20.1 7.5 20 7.2zM13.9 10.9c-0.2 0.2-0.4 0.6-0.3 0.9l0.8 4.2 -3.8-2c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1V3.1l1.9 3.8c0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.8 0.6L17 8 13.9 10.9z"/></svg>',
        "full-star":
        '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="luna-icon-star-stroke"><path d="M7.813 18.663l3.718-1.973a1 1 0 0 1 .938 0l3.718 1.973-.727-4.146a1 1 0 0 1 .29-.891l3.025-2.927-4.168-.59a1 1 0 0 1-.758-.55L12 5.776l-1.849 3.781a1 1 0 0 1-.758.551l-4.168.59 3.026 2.927a1 1 0 0 1 .29.89l-.728 4.147zm-.87 2.725a1 1 0 0 1-1.453-1.056l.989-5.638-4.114-3.98a1 1 0 0 1 .555-1.709l5.668-.802 2.514-5.142a1 1 0 0 1 1.796 0l2.514 5.142 5.668.802a1 1 0 0 1 .555 1.709l-4.114 3.98.99 5.638a1 1 0 0 1-1.454 1.056L12 18.706l-5.057 2.682z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>'
);

$star-color: #A5C6FF;
$border-color: #3B63F9;
$empty-color: #FFFFFF;

$data-svg-prefix: "data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,";

.starRating {
  fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  label {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    &:before {
      height: 1rem;
      width: 1rem;
      content: " ";
      display: block;
    }
  }

  .rating {
    border: none;
    float: left;

    > input {
      display: none;

      &:checked {
        ~ {
          label {
            color: $star-color;

            &:hover {
              color: $star-color;

              ~ {
                label {
                  color: $star-color;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

        + {
          label {
            &:hover {
              color: $star-color;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    > label {
      &:before {
        margin: 5px;
        font-size: 1.25em;
        display: inline-block;
        background-image: url($data-svg-prefix + map-get($icons, "full-star"));
      }

      color: $empty-color;
      float: right;

      &:hover {
        ~ {
          input {
            &:checked {
              ~ {
                label {
                  color: $star-color;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    > .half {
      &:before {
        background-image: url($data-svg-prefix + map-get($icons, "half-star"));
        position: absolute;
      }
    }

    &:not(:checked) {
      > label {
        &:hover {
          color: $star-color;

          ~ {
            label {
              color: $star-color;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5"><label class="full" for="star5" title="5 stars"></label><input
    type="radio" id="star4.5" name="rating" value="4.5"><label class="half" for="star4.5"
    title="4.5 stars"></label><input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4"><label class="full" for="star4"
    title="4 stars"></label><input type="radio" id="star3.5" name="rating" value="3.5"><label class="half" for="star3.5"
    title="3.5 stars"></label><input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3"><label class="full" for="star3"
    title="3 stars"></label><input type="radio" id="star2.5" name="rating" value="2.5"><label class="half" for="star2.5"
    title="2.5 stars"></label><input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2"><label class="full" for="star2"
    title="2 stars"></label><input type="radio" id="star1.5" name="rating" value="1.5"><label class="half" for="star1.5"
    title="1.5 stars"></label><input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1"><label class="full" for="star1"
    title="1 stars"></label><input type="radio" id="star0.5" name="rating" value="0.5"><label class="half" for="star0.5"
    title="0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/amir734jj/pen/abNYZyo

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading your SVG with a `background-image` property. Your SVG then becomes an image/file. You can't affect its color or background with any property.

If you want to do so with only your SCSS code you would have to add every SVG variant you're needing into you `$icons : (...)`, for example `"half-star-blue"` etc, then change the `background-image` property on hover.
You will however not be able to use any transition for this property.

Also, it is not very recommended to do so. If you have SVG code, you should put it in your HTML so that you're able to alter its color with the `fill` property.

The most convenient way to use and alter an SVG is to put it in your html code, and not in the css.
Since your stars and half stars are re-used, the ebst way is to define then as symbols in an SVG tag, then to use the `use` tag like this (it is just an example, modify the color etc as you wish ; also I had to modify a bit your svg icons so the display could get better) :
https://codepen.io/aurelienbobenrieth/pen/bGpvgwo

Comment: If instead of assigning `background-image: url(..)` property, I assign `content: url(..)`, its the same result. Can you please guide me on how to correctly use SVGs